# How to use child class as parent class type in dart / flutter?

Tags: oop, flutter, dart

**Short question**

> In dart inheritance, how to use the child class in something that
>   expects the parent type ?

**Full case**

In this `#flutter_clock` repo on github:

```
https://github.com/flutter/flutter_clock/blob/master/digital_clock/lib/main.dart
```

the `ClockCustomizer` takes a function that takes `ClockModel` as input, but the initial model isn't enough for me so I've made  `class ExtendedClockModel extends ClockModel` and put all the extra functions in it.

When I try to replace the input to `ExtendedClockModel` instead it gives me error :

> The argument type 'DigitalClock Function(ExtendedClockModel)' can't be
>   assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(ClockModel)'.

**How to use the `ExtendedClockModel` as `ClockModel` type to have the extended functionality as input ? and is this code strategy good for scalability or there is another method of work ?**

Comment: pass it as `(extendedClockModelchildInstance as ClockModel)`

Comment: tried it , same error : The argument type 'DigitalClock Function(ExtendedClockModel, ClockModel)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(ClockModel)'.da

Comment: Can you post more of your code? It is going to be hard to solve this without a longer code sample.

Comment: Is `DigitalClock` a Widget? Just to be sure

Comment: The error you mentioned in the comment differs from the one in the question.  On the error in the comment you are asking for two parameters in your function and it only gives one on the original.